# Installing Magick++ in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, windows, magick++

I have recently installed ImageMagick libraries for C++. I have no prior experience with C++ GUI but I'm very good in C++ command line programming.

I have installed ImageMagick in Windows through an .exe file and copied libraries and header files to C++ but whenever I try to run any demo program I am consistently getting this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Sufiyan, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall Magick::Image::~Image(void)" (__imp_??1Image@Magick@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Magick::Image::write(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_?write@Image@Magick@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall Magick::Image::pixelColor(long,long,class Magick::Color const &)" (__imp_?pixelColor@Image@Magick@@QAEXJJABVColor@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall Magick::Color::~Color(void)" (__imp_??1Color@Magick@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Magick::Geometry::~Geometry(void)" (__imp_??1Geometry@Magick@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Magick::Image::Image(class Magick::Geometry const &,class Magick::Color const &)" (__imp_??0Image@Magick@@QAE@ABVGeometry@1@ABVColor@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Magick::Geometry::Geometry(char const *)" (__imp_??0Geometry@Magick@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Magick::Color::Color(char const *)" (__imp_??0Color@Magick@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl Magick::InitializeMagick(char const *)" (__imp_?InitializeMagick@Magick@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Z-Axis\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Sufiyan\Debug\Sufiyan.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

These are my laptop Specs:

- Windows 7 64 bit.
- Visual C++ 2010 Express x86
- ImageMagick x86

This is how I tried installing it:

1. Installed Visual C++ 2010 Express
2. Installed ImageMagick
3. Copy ImageMagick Lib and Includes in Visual C++ 2010
4. Selected Win32 -> Windows -> Empty project (didn't work)
5. Selected Win32 -> DLL (didn't work)
6. Selected Win32 -> Static (didn't work)

but when I run any code it gives the error mentioned above.

Someone has suggested this solution:

> You need a starting point, go to
>   c:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.1-Q16\Magick++_demos.
>   Click on the button workspace, build, and run.
>   Assuming that's successful, use the button workspace as a template for your own custom code.

I've tried this too, dozens of times, and am continuously getting this error:

> The Project must be Converted to current Visual C++ project format.
>    After it has been converted you will not be able to edit this project in previous version of visual studio.
>   Convert and open this project ?

When I click `Yes` nothing happens, nothing shows on the screen - blank Visual C++ screen with no project open.

I desperately want to know: What is causing this error and why even the demo programs are not working?

Comment: You need to supply the compile ImageMagick library to import those methods.

Comment: @Ramhound can you please elaborate ?
all what i did is copied lib and include in Visual C++ VC folder and they are available to be used in the code (when i press CTRL+SPACE)
what do you mean by compile ImageMagick Library ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to build ImageMagick yourself, the problem may come form the different version of compiler.

Follow the directions in [Advanced windows installation of ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-windows-installation.php).
At end of the above page, there is a solution of link error, make sure you have set the preprocessor. I just followed it to build a project successfully.