# How to install php_imagick on wamp64

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, imagemagick, wamp

I've been trying to install php_imagick on wamp64 without any luck.

The desired goal is for WordPress to stop showing the error message:

> The optional module, Imagick, is not installed or has been disabled.

You can also skip reading and view the images attached below.

**My setup:**

```
Wamp64 Windows 10 Release Version 3.2.3.3 64 Bits [Windows Build: 19041]
PHP Version: 7.4.9
Build Date: Aug 4 2020 11:45:36
Windows: NT *username* 10.0 build 19041 (Windows 10) AMD64
Compiler Visual: C++ 2017
Architecture: x64
Loaded Configuration File: C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.46\bin\php.ini
Thread Safety: enabled
```

I tried installing the following ImageMagick files:

```
1) ImageMagick-7.0.10-30-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe
----A) php_imagick-3.4.3rc1-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip
----B) php_imagick-3.4.3rc1-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip
2) ImageMagick-7.0.10-30-Q16-x64-dll.exe
----A) php_imagick-3.4.3rc1-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip
----B) php_imagick-3.4.4rc2-7.3-ts-vc15-x64.zip
3) ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-Q16-x64-dll.exe (Current)
----A) php_imagick-3.4.4rc2-7.3-ts-vc15-x64.zip (Current)
----B) php_imagick-3.4.3rc1-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip
----C) php_imagick-3.4.3rc1-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip
```

**What I did:**

I first installed the EXE file and then extracted from the zip file just the php_imagick.dll file into this folder:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\ext
```

Which matches my currently used PHP version (see images later for more information[php.ini]).

I tried restarting Wamp, rebuilding symlinks by switching PHP/Apache versions.

Will also be worth mentioning that I at one point tried extracting the full zip into the 'ext' folder under a folder named 'php_imagick' as shown below and did manage to get this error:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\ext\php_imagick\php_imagick.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.)
```

but mostly I receive these errors:

```
[25-Sep-2020 08:58:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_imagick.dll' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.9/ext/php_imagick.dll (The specified module could not be found.), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.9/ext/php_php_imagick.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

When I install Magick using the EXE, I make sure to check the `install to the path`, Change the folder to `C:\ImageMagick`, and install the `legacy drivers` if possible, as suggested on Stack OverFlow.
(I also make sure to uninstall the last version I tried each time)

I have Visual Studio installed and a bunch of redistributables and also both x86 and x64 versions of these:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Without any luck, I went ahead and read several Stack OverFlow posts and could not find a solution.

[How to install ImageMagick with Wampserver 3.0.0 64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927486/how-to-install-imagemagick-with-wampserver-3-0-0-64)

[step-by-step instructions for installing IMAGEMAGICK on WAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942523/step-by-step-instructions-for-installing-imagemagick-on-wamp)

[Installing php_imagick.dll PHP extension on wampserver 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440968/installing-php-imagick-dll-php-extension-on-wampserver-2-2)

[Unable to install php_imagick.dll on wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495644/unable-to-install-php-imagick-dll-on-wamp)

[Imagick delegates installation on WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400717/imagick-delegates-installation-on-wamp)

[How to install ImageMagick with Wampserver 3.0.0 64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927486/how-to-install-imagemagick-with-wampserver-3-0-0-64)

[step-by-step instructions for installing IMAGEMAGICK on WAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942523/step-by-step-instructions-for-installing-imagemagick-on-wamp)

[Installing php_imagick.dll PHP extension on wampserver 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440968/installing-php-imagick-dll-php-extension-on-wampserver-2-2)

[Unable to install php_imagick.dll on wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495644/unable-to-install-php-imagick-dll-on-wamp)

[Imagick delegates installation on WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400717/imagick-delegates-installation-on-wamp)

[WAMP PHP Startup Error: Unable to load dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197659/wamp-php-startup-error-unable-to-load-dynamic-library)

[Installing ImageMagick extension with php/windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858439/installing-imagemagick-extension-with-php-windows?answertab=active#tab-top)

[Linker error when trying to use ImageMagick as static libraries with Visual Studio compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639667/linker-error-when-trying-to-use-imagemagick-as-static-libraries-with-visual-stud)

[Installing Magick++ in Visual C++ 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407353/installing-magick-in-visual-c-2010)

[Installing Magick++ in visual studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864570/installing-magick-in-visual-studio-2019)

[ImageMagick with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664624/imagemagick-with-visual-studio)

[WampServer and Imagemagick, imagick php module not recogized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368188/wampserver-and-imagemagick-imagick-php-module-not-recogized?rq=1)

[Cannot load imagick library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609951/cannot-load-imagick-library/48600203)

[ImageMagick not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951702/imagemagick-not-working)

What can I try next?

[image: Wamp Version]

[image: Versions I Tried]

[image: Wamp Settings]

typo in line 955: .php=.dll
[image: PHP.INI and revisions]

[image: PHPINFO Test File]

[image: Where Everything Started - WordPress]

[image: PHPINFO - Running The Test File]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hired a freelancer to fix this for us.

- **Uninstall** any versions of WampServer and ImageMagick you have installed

  - Don't forget to backup your database and www folder before you uninstall
  - We are going to install a trustable software called Chocolatey that will help us fix a bunch of errors with Wamp64 and it's extensions as well as help us update those applications with one command.

> For those of you who already fixed this before using Chocolatey and
> now seeing this error message again simply update Wamp and ImageMagick
> using the choco commands provided on their website and then read **my
> note** under `4)` for more information

---

1. **Run** PowerShell **as Admin**

   - Follow this guide to **Download** chocolatey https://chocolatey.org/install
2. Use the same methods to **Download** Wamp64 https://chocolatey.org/packages/wamp-server

   - Run Wamp from the newly created shortcut on your desktop
   - Change the PHP version to 7.4.9 or the latest and only then move
     to the other steps
   - Don't worry about the fact the folder is named Wamp and not Wamp64. It's still the 64bit version. You can check this in the about section of Wamp
3. **Download** https://chocolatey.org/packages/imagemagick
4. **Download** https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ImageMagick-7.0.7-11-vc15-x64.zip

   - Note: If that doesn't work, they probably updated again. Just try the same methods using newer versions then these. I will first try more recent versions of php_imagick instead of replacing the ImageMagick core DLL files. One thing I will not do is give up.
5. **Extract** And **Copy** all `CORE_RL` and `IM_MOD_RL` **DLL** files into `C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.4.9` where `php.exe` is located

   *(Do not run any EXE file from here as we already installed ImageMagick)*
6. **Download** https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.4/php_imagick-3.4.4-7.4-ts-vc15-x64.zip
7. **Extract** and **Copy** just the `php_imagick.dll` file to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.4.9\ext`
8. **Open** your php.ini file by left-clicking Wamp->PHP->php.ini and then make sure you delete all leftovers and **add** below any `extention=` line the code below:

> extention=imagick

```
(Apparently, New PHP versions require writing it without the "php_"...".dll" parts)
```

8. **Restart** Wamp **by closing it and reopening it from its shortcut**

[image: WordPress stopped complainin]

- This is by far the only solution I could get running.

  - choco:

    Google = https://www.google.com/search?q=chocolatey

    2019 = http://web.archive.org/web/20190101113929/https://chocolatey.org/

    2018 = http://web.archive.org/web/20180414000310/https://chocolatey.org/

Enjoy

Comment: I would appreciate any comments or suggestions for edits as I was super tired when writing this

Comment: I followed only steps from 5 to 8, but copying CORE_RL and IM_MOD_RL dlls files to apache\bin path as commented @Manfred Körkel and It worked. Also works if you install from chocolatey or with ImageMagick binary (https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) adding dir path and no copying dll's from step 5. I was having troubles because I was downloaded PHP 8.1 version from imagick DLL instead my PHP 7.4 version

Answer (score 3):

I use wampserver 3.2.3 64bit together with PHP 7.3.

- Copying the CORE_RL and IM_MOD_RL DLLs into the PHP root direcory as [orr burgel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6886886/orr-burgel) recommended [in item #5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64067477/17074151) did not work for me.
- I had to copy these DLLs into c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin.

Comment: For those who have multiple PHP versions (in my case 7.4.26+8.1.4 on WAMP 3.2.6-64) the following worked for me: 1. copy CORE_RL and IM_MOD_RL from php_imagick-3.7.0-8.1-ts-vs16-x64 to apache/bin directory; 2. copy appropriate php_imagick.dll (from php_imagick-3.7.0-7.4-ts-vc15-x64 and php_imagick-3.7.0-8.1-ts-vs16-x64) to php.ver/ext/; 3. add line extension=imagick in both php.ini in php.ver directory; 4. restart WAMP and switch back and forth between PHP versions to update the apache/bin/php.ini. imagick packages available from [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick); TS=Threaded Safety